# Application-defined or Object-defined error in Excel code

Tags: vba, excel

My code below is used to open an **order report** file and a **list of keywords** file then use AutoFilter to filter required data in **order report** file by a **list of keywords** then copy to another worksheet.

My problem is that when this code runs:

`OrderCount = wsOrder.Range("A2", wsOrder.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count`

...the error **Application-defined or Object-defined error** occurrs, but only on certain **order report** files. I have 2 exactly layout, criteria workbook only data is different, yet one file is able to be run but the other does not.

It runs fine on one workbook (below) but nor the other.
[image: img]

[image: img]

```
Public Sub btn1_Click()
    Dim i As Double, N As Double, strKeyWord As String, myCount As Integer
    Dim OrderCount As Integer, SubTotal As Range, Country As Range
    Dim DisCount As Range, Quantity As Range, ItemName As Range
    Dim OrderName As Range, RequiredData As Range, wsOrder As Worksheet
    Dim wsResult As Worksheet, wsCondition As Worksheet, wbOrder As Workbook
    Dim wbCondition As Workbook, OrderFile As String, ConditionFile As String

    OrderFile = Application.GetOpenFilename() 'Open Order wb
    Set wbOrder = Workbooks.Open(OrderFile)
    Set wsOrder = wbOrder.Worksheets(1)
    ConditionFile = Application.GetOpenFilename() 'Open Condition wb
    Set wbCondition = Workbooks.Open(ConditionFile)
    Set wsResult = wbCondition.Worksheets(1)
    Set wsCondition = wbCondition.Worksheets(2)
    myCount = Application.CountA(wsCondition.Range("A:A")) 'use CountA (all non-blanks)
    For i = 2 To myCount Step 1
        strKeyWord = wsCondition.Range("A" & i)
        wsOrder.Range("R:R").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strKeyWord & "*"
        If wsOrder.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row > 1 Then
            Set SubTotal = wsOrder.Range("I2", wsOrder.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            Set Country = wsOrder.Range("AG2", wsOrder.Range("AG" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            Set DisCount = wsOrder.Range("N2", wsOrder.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            Set Quantity = wsOrder.Range("Q2", wsOrder.Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            Set OrderName = wsOrder.Range("A2", wsOrder.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            Set ItemName = wsOrder.Range("R2", wsOrder.Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            Set RequiredData = Union(SubTotal, Country, _
                        DisCount, Quantity, OrderName, ItemName)
            RequiredData.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            OrderCount = wsOrder.Range("A2", wsOrder.Range("A" & Rows.Count) _
                        .End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count
            With wsResult
                If OrderCount >= 2 Then
                    For N = 1 To OrderCount Step 1
                        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = strKeyWord
                        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "Available"
                    Next N
                Else
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = strKeyWord
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "Available"
                End If
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial
            End With
        Else
            With wsResult
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = strKeyWord
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "No Order"
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "N/A"
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "N/A"
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "N/A"
            End With
        End If
        OrderCount = 0
    Next i
    wbCondition.Sheets("Result").Activate
    wsOrder.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there some significance to the two blanked-out screen shots you included?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your edit suggestion.
The blanked-out screen shots is some data that I cannot show to the public. And I think my error is occurred only in the A column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it *must* be because your "condition" file is a *post 2003* excel workbook while your *not working* "order" file is an *up to 2003* excel workbook.

hence your "condition" workbook worksheets have some 1 million rows each, while your "order" workbook worksheets have some 65k rows each

in:

```
OrderCount = wsOrder.Range("A2", wsOrder.Range("A" & Rows.Count) _
                    .End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count
```

that unqualified `Rows.Count` is implicitly assuming the active sheet as the one to count the rows of

the last opened workbook is "condition" one, so `wsOrder.Range("A" & Rows.Count)` is  trying to access "order" workbook sheet some 1million th row, while it has up to 65 k...

a solution could be simply swap the workbook opening sequence:

```
ConditionFile = Application.GetOpenFilename() 'Open Condition wb first
Set wbCondition = Workbooks.Open(ConditionFile)
Set wsResult = wbCondition.Worksheets(1)
Set wsCondition = wbCondition.Worksheets(2)

OrderFile = Application.GetOpenFilename() 'Open Order wb as the last one
Set wbOrder = Workbooks.Open(OrderFile)
Set wsOrder = wbOrder.Worksheets(1)
```

thus having "order" workbook as the *active* one

but is best practice to avoid relying on `Active`/`Selection` coding pattern and use fully qualified range references instead:

```
OrderCount = wsOrder.Range("A2", wsOrder.Range("A" & wsOrder.Rows.Count) _
                    .End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count
```

so I'd suggest you this latter fix

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I try to fix with your suggestion but it still the same. The point is that there are reports that works well with my code and the others are not. Funny is that the even report days work and odd days don't. 
About avoid active/selection. Do you have any tips for me since i am a newbie with excel VBA :D

Comment: there would be too many relevant tips to give and I would skip most of them. but two of them stand out: 1) don't use `Active`/`Activate`/`Selection`/`Select` pattern 2) always use `Option Explicit` at the very top of all your modules